# How to add values to a class from another class in Scala?

Tags: scala, function, class, methods

Input: `class Number(changeNum: ChangeNum, 32)`

Output: `changeNum = 32.0`

Each time the class Method will be called, a number will be appended to the end of the last number. So if you call `class Number(changeNum: ChangeNum, number: Int)` again, with number being 45, output of changeNum in the `Class ChangeNum` will be 3245.0

How do I do the following in Scala? Here is what I attempted below.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent
import javafx.event.EventHandler

class ChangeNum() {
    def given(): Double = {
        0.0
    }
}

class Number(changeNum: ChangeNum, number: Int) extends EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
    override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
        var changeNum += number
    }
}
```

Comment: If the question is about Scala, why did you tag it Java?

Comment: Hi thelegend27! You have to make it so that your function returns the updated value if you want to use it that. Or you have to declare the variable before the function (outside of the function)

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I wrote it in the answer below, but basically just declare it like this outside: var changeNum: Int, and then remove the var in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to have the var updated as you wish, you have to put it outside of the function. What you're doing now is initialising a new value every time that you add to every time the function is being called.

For example you could do it like this:

```
class Number(changeNum: ChangeNum, number: Int) extends 
EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
var changeNumber = changeNum.toString
override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
changeNumber.append(number.toString)
}
```

Also, you wanted to append each number to the end. An easy way of doing this is simply put it to a string and use the append function.

Comment: I can't see where you have anything named calculator. It looks like you're mixing a lot of java and scala code. It might help you to do it in Java first if you're unsure about Scala. But it sounds like the error is that you don't define a variable named calculator?

Comment: Also I moved the var decleration to be inside the class but outside of the function. This means when you creat a new Number, (apply), you set the start numbers too. I also renamed it to changeNumber so you can see better what I mean. But the java code you're doing with event, I have no idea about

Comment: I did another edit, I didn't see you wanted to append the numbers onto each other at the end. So I added a part where it turns into strings and simply appends the number as a string onto the next one. Hope this is helpful.